# Regularized Logistic Regression Cost Function Log(1-p) = inf

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I am trying to implement logistic regression cost function.
I tested my implementation and it works fine for different datasets.
But when I was trying to solve by new dataset, I realized that the second part of below equation (`term2`) always is `inf`. The problem is the value passed to the `np.log()` function is 0, so it gives me `inf`. Actually, the answer of `sigmoid(hypothesis(x,theta)) = 1`.

```
term1 = -y*(np.log(sigmoid(hypothesis(x,theta))))
term2 = ((1-y)*(np.log(1 - sigmoid(hypothesis(x,theta)))))
infunc1 = term1 - term2 
infunc2 = (lambda_*np.sum(theta[1:]**2))/(2*m)
j = (np.sum(infunc1)/m)+infunc2
```

The first solution I think is to add a very small value to 0 to prevent from `inf`. But I do not know this is correct or not. (based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125319/python-divide-by-zero-encountered-in-log-logistic-regression)).

What should I when the answer of multiplying some features to weights is zero and pass this answer to `log`?

Thanks for any advice.
Happy coding

Comment: Your intuition is correct, adding an epsilon solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you. Should I add this small value to the all of the elements of matrix or just the elements cause `inf` answer? What happen if I do the other one?

Comment: You could add epsilon to all the values, or use numpy masked opetations (to avoid nans and infs), e.g. `np.ma.log(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

As friends told, you just need to add a very small value to `log` function:

```
epsilon = 1e-5
term1 = -y*(np.log(epsilon+sigmoid(hypothesis(x,theta))))
term2 = ((1-y)*(np.log(epsilon+1 - sigmoid(hypothesis(x,theta)))))
infunc1 = term1 - term2 
infunc2 = (lambda_*np.sum(theta[1:]**2))/(2*m)
j = (np.sum(infunc1)/m)+infunc2
```